# Why do I have such a hard time setting breakpoints in Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, breakpoints

I've been experiencing this for years, and it's happened across several computers. I click on a line to set a breakpoint in Chrome, and one of the following happens without about equal frequency:

1. Nothing happens.
2. There's a long delay, like 2-10 seconds, and then the breakpoint appears.
3. The breakpoint appears on a different line, with about a 50% chance of appearing on the correct line during execution.
4. The breakpoint is correctly set.

This has been driving me crazy for the longest time. I'd assumed it was just a bug, but I can't believe that such a commonly used feature would remain so buggy for such a long time, so I'm wondering if it's somehow me.

Does anyone else experience this and/or know how to fix it? It's seriously annoying.

Comment: This happens for me too.  Does your JS have source URLs? Do you have an awful lot of JS? (1.6MB)

Comment: Just jQuery and Angular (both minified) and maybe 40 lines of my own. Doesn't seem like a lot, but could that be the reason?

Comment: same here with angular, query and other stuffs.